# dynamic li class active in laravel

Tags: php, html, laravel

here's my route

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index')->name('account.index')->middleware('auth');
Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@index')->name('dashboard.show')->middleware('auth');
```

and on my dashboard

```
<div class="main-menu-content">
        <ul class="navigation navigation-main" id="main-menu-navigation" data-menu="menu-navigation">
          <li {{ request()->route()->getName() === 'dashboard.index' ? ' class=active' : '' }}><a href="/dashboard"><i class="ft-home"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="">Dashboard</span></a>
          </li>
          <li {{ request()->route()->getName() === 'account.index' ? ' class=active' : '' }}><a href="/account"><i class="ft-user"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="">Account</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
```

What I am trying to do here is to make the `li` class active dynmic but I tried the above code and there's no class active though i'm on the dashboard and I also checked when I am in the account `li` still not highlighting as active . Could someone please tell me what's wrong?

Comment: The best way to test it is to echo out the name before the UL, to see what exactly it is. Your dashboard route is named `dashboard.show`, not `dashboard.index`, and your account route has no name at all.

Comment: @aynber problem solved sir. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't name the account route, so you have to change the account route to this:

```php
Route::get('/account', 'AccountController@index')->name('account.index')->middleware('auth');
```

You did name the dashboard route to `dashboard.show`, so your `li` tag for the dashboard has to be equal to `dashboard.show` instead of `dashboard.index`

Answer (score -1):

```
<li class="@if(Route::currentRouteName() == 'dashboard.show' active @endif"><a href="/dashboard"><i class="ft-home"></i><span class="menu-title" data-i18n="">Dashboard</span></a>
```

Comment: Here are some guidelines for [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)?. This provided answer may be correct, but it could benefit from an explanation. Code only answers are not considered "good" answers